# Modulization Gone Awry

Tags: c, image-processing, module, modularity, pgm

So I had one large function that worked. Then I decided to modify it and now I am just printing out a black square. I am attaching my code to see if any one would understand what is happening. These three function where once large function:
Function 1

```
int
readpgm (pgm_type * header, char input[80], char output[80])
{
    FILE *instream;

    int size, read;
    instream = fopen (input, "rb");

    fileChecker (instream);

    fscanf (instream, "%2s%d%d%d", header->filetype, &header->width,
        &header->height, &header->maxgray);

    if (!header->filetype[0] == 'P' || !header->filetype[1] == '5') {
        fatal ("Incorrect Type");
    }

    size = header->width * header->height;

    header->p = malloc (size * sizeof (char));

    read = fread (header->p, 1, size, instream);
    if (read != size) {
        fatal ("Incorrect Size");
    }

    return size;
}

void
crop (pgm_type * header, char output[80])
{
    printf ("Height: %i, Width: %i, Total pixels: %i \n", header->height,
        header->width, header->height * header->width);

    int temp, y1, y2, x1, x2, wide, high;

    printf ("Please Enter x1 y1 x2 y2 \n");


    scanf ("%i %i %i %i", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
    if (y1 > y2) {
        temp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = temp;
    }
    if (x1 > x2) {
        temp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp;
    }
    wide = x2 - x1 + 1;
    high = y2 - y1 + 1;

    printFile (wide, high, x1, x2, y1, y1, header, output);
}

void
printFile (int wide, int high, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2,
       pgm_type * header, char output[80])
{
    FILE *outstream;

    outstream = fopen (output, "wb");

    fileChecker (outstream);

    fprintf (outstream, "%2s\n%i %i\n%i\n", header->filetype, wide, high,
         header->maxgray);

    pixel image[header->height][header->width];
    pixel *pix = malloc ((wide * high) * sizeof (char));

    int a = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b < header->height; ++b) {
        for (int c = 0; c < header->width; ++c) {
            image[b][c] = header->p[a];
            ++a;
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = y1; i <= y2; ++i) {
        for (int j = x1; j <= x2; ++j) {
            pix[k] = image[i][j];
            ++k;
        }
    }

    fwrite (pix, 1, (wide * high) * sizeof (pixel), outstream);
    free (pix);
    fclose (outstream);
}
```

The first two function are call in main.

Comment: This line looks wrong to me: pixel image[header->height][header->width]

Comment: @whoplisp That would be a 2d array if height was 4 and width was 5, it would be image[4][5].

Comment: I don't want to derail, but I hope your code is not part of any program available to the public. Fixed-size char arrays without length-checking are prone to buffer overflows.

Comment: @Joe I know that it is a 2d array, however whenever I used those I ran into problems. I find it much more reliable to use malloced 1d arrays.

Comment: @Whoplisp would that cause my aplication to print a black square?

Comment: @Joe the 2D array of variable size may very well be a problem. You have to go through the program from the beginning and make sure that every step works. Your PGM header parser is very simple (scanf). You should add some checks to make sure it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
//gcc c2.c -std=c99  -g -Wall -Wextra
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct pgm_type pgm_type;
struct pgm_type{
  char filetype[2];
  int width,height,maxgray;
  unsigned char*p;
};


int
readpgm (pgm_type * header, char*fn)
{
    FILE *instream;

    int size, read;
    instream = fopen (fn,"rb");

    assert(instream);

    fscanf (instream, "%2s%d%d%d", header->filetype, &header->width,
        &header->height, &header->maxgray);
    printf("%2s %d %d %d\n",header->filetype,header->width,
       header->height,header->maxgray);

    if (!header->filetype[0] == 'P' || !header->filetype[1] == '5') {
      printf ("Incorrect Type");
    }

    size = header->width * header->height;

    header->p = malloc (size * sizeof (char));

    read = fread (header->p, 1, size, instream);
    if (read != size) {
      printf ("Incorrect Size");
    }

    return size;
}

void
printFile (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2,pgm_type * header, char*fn)
{
    FILE *outstream;
    int wide=x2-x1+1,high=y2-y1+1;
    printf("cropping to %dx%d\n",wide,high);
    outstream = fopen (fn, "wb");

    assert (outstream);

    fprintf (outstream, "%2s\n%i %i\n%i\n", header->filetype, wide, high,
         header->maxgray);

    unsigned char image[header->height][header->width];
    unsigned char *pix = malloc ((wide * high) * sizeof (char));

    int a = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b < header->height; ++b) {
        for (int c = 0; c < header->width; ++c) {
            image[b][c] = header->p[a];
            ++a;
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (int j = y1; j <= y2; ++j) {
        for (int i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
            pix[k] = image[j][i];
            ++k;
        }
    }

    fwrite (pix, wide,high, outstream);
    free (pix);
    fclose (outstream);
}


int
main()
{
  pgm_type h;
  readpgm(&h,"lena.pgm");
  printFile(64,129,32,230,&h,"o2.pgm");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you read my post, I had it working before I broke up the functions.

Comment: Thank I just need to add a function to sort x and y and this will work